# Haskell: Monad transformers and global state

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm trying to learn Haskell. I'm trying to write a programm that contains a "global state": `Vars`. I want to change a component of the state (e.g. `var1`) each time I call a function. The change can be a simple function on the components (e.g. +4). Also, it prints out the component changed. Here is what I've done so far (but I'm stuck). Edit: after running the code I want to see the recent version of the global state.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

data Vars = Vars {
 var1 :: Int,
 var2 :: Float
} deriving (Show)

sample :: StateT Vars IO a
sample = do 
        a <- change
        liftIO $ print a
        -- I want to call change again and apply more change to the state


change  :: StateT Vars IO a
change  = do
        dd <- get
         -- I don't know what to do next!

main = do 
  runStateT sample (Vars 20 3)
  evalStateT sample (Vars 20 3)
```

Comment: Could you please specify desired output of the program? What you want to observe after running `main` function?

Comment: @Shersh Thanks for the hint. I just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to solve your problem step-by-step starting from easier and small parts. It's important skill in programming and FP teaches you that skill in nice way. Also, working with `State` monad and especially with several effects in monad-transformers helps you to reason about effects and understand things better.

1. You want to update `var1` inside your immutable data type. This can be done only by creating new object. So let's write such function:

   ```
   plusFour :: Vars -> Vars
   plusFour (Vars v1 v2) = Vars (v1 + 4) v2
   ```

   There exist ways in Haskell to write this function much shorter though less understandable, but we don't care about those things now.
2. Now you want to use this function inside `State` monad to update immutable state and by this simulate mutability. What can be told about this function only by looking at its type signature: `change :: StateT Vars IO a`? We can say that this function have several effects: it has access to `Vars` state and it can do arbitrary `IO` actions. Also this function returns value of type `a`. Hmm, this last one is strange. What is `a`? What this function should return? In imperative programming this function will have type `void` or `Unit`. It just *do* things, it doesn't return everything. Only updates context. So it's result type should be `()`. It can be different. For example we might want to return new `Vars` after change. But this is generally bad approach in programming. It makes this function more complex.
3. After we understood what type function should have (try to always start with defining types) we can implement it. We want to change our state. There're functions that operates with stateful parts of our context. Basically, you interested in this one:

   [`modify :: Monad m => (s -> s) -> StateT s m ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:modify)

   `modify` function takes function which updates state. After you run this function you can observe that state is modified according to passed function. Now `change` can be written like this:

   ```
   change :: StateT Vars IO ()
   change = modify plusFour
   ```

   You can implement `modify` (and thus `change` using only `put` and `get` functions which is nice exercise for beginner).
4. Let's now call `change` function from some other function. What does calling mean in this case? It means that you execute monadic action `change`. This action changes your context, you don't care about it's result because it's `()`. But if you run `get` function (which binds whole state to variable) after `change` you can observe new change. If you want to print only changed component, like `var1` you can use `gets` function. And, again, what type should `sample` have? What should it return? If on the caller side you're interested only in resulting state, then, again, it should be `()` like this:

   ```
   sample :: StateT Vars IO ()
   sample = do
       change
       v1 <- gets var1
       liftIO $ print v1
       change
       v1' <- gets var1 
       liftIO $ print v1'  -- this should be v1 + 4
   ```

This should add you some understanding of what is happening. Monad transformers require some time to get used to them though it's a powerful tool (not perfect but extremely useful).

As as a side note I want to add that these function can be written much nicer using common Haskell design patterns. But you don't need to care about those right now, just try to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the precise answer! Did you mean "Lenses" by "design pattern"?

Comment: @4xx «Lenses» is a library but it brought part of that pattern. I mean, that type of `change` function should be `change :: (MonadState s m, HasVar1 s) => m ()`.

Comment: can you please refer me to some source explaining why "change" should be written that way?

Comment: @4xx This video is really nice and clear: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZPup5Iuaqw